# Matrices and linear maps: finding image and kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$V= \left\langle\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$$ and $$W=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 2 &0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 1 &1\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle.$$
Let $T:V \to W$ such that

$T\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 3 &1\end{pmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 2 & 2 \\0 & 6 &2\end{pmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\0 & 3/2 &1/2\end{pmatrix}$.

How can I find the image and the kernel of $T$?

Comment: Details: normally, I have no problem with vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$, but matrices confuse me a bit.

Comment: If it helps, you can think of each of this matrices as a vector in $\mathbb R^6$, for instance $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$ can be thought of as $(0,0,-1, 0,1,0)$. You can work with vectors and then translate back to matrices. Recall that [same finite dimension vector spaces are isomorphic](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Same_Dimensional_Vector_Spaces_are_Isomorphic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that images all multiple by scalar and hence image is $1$ dimensional. Therefore, the kernel is $2$ dimensional. Try to take it from here.
If we call the matrices $v_1,v_2,v_3$ then
 $T(v_2-2v_1)=0$ and also
$T(v_1-2v_3)=0$ and hence 
$$ker (T)=span\{2v_1-v_2,v_1-2v_3\}.$$

Comment: I see. But could you follow a more standard procedure to find the kernel (so that I can see what to do in similar cases)?

Comment: just take a linear combination $v=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and assume $$T(v)=aT(v_1)+bT(v_2)+cT(v_3)=0.$$ This is a homogenus linear system and you need to find its solotions, that is $ker(T)$.

Comment: I see. How can I use the matrix associated to the linear map with respect to those bases of V and W to represent the system?

Comment: your matrices are $v_1,v_2,v_3$ there images are $T(v_1),T(v_2),T(v_3)$ and your looking for conditions on $a,b,c$.